# Why isn't my image drawing correctly in my platformer?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been following a tutorial online just to get a simple 2D platformer working and I can't understand why it can't get the boxes to draw? Also the poorly drawn stick figure is being drawn in 2 parts that are then broken

I've tried messing with the values for 'stickman.png', 'woodenboxbutsmaller.png' and window sizes but I just can't get it do it correctly? I think it's trying to draw the stick figure as boxes for some reason which is why it would be appearing all broken up, but it should be trying to use the 'woodenbox png'

```py
import random
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

display_width = 800   # game window width and height
display_height = 600

background = (255,255,255)
bg = pygame.image.load('smb.png')

black = (0,0,0)   # some colours for buttons and stuff
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

object_width = 50 # width hitbox of the object
 
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('the greatest 2d platformer of all time: the game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):   # button function allows menu to work later
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
  
def message_display(text):   # message function that makes messages appear after various actions (usually crashing)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',100)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def text_objects(text, font):   # some text thing? think it just allows messages to work
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):   # i think this is for the floating squares?
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def game_intro():    # basically the main menu

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # sets white background and adds the text and buttons for the main menu
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",25)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("the greatest 2d platformer of all time: the game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("start",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green, game_loop)
        button(":(",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,pygame.quit)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, startx, starty):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('stickman.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.center = [startx, starty]

    def update(self):
        pass
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, startx, starty):
        super().__init__("stickman.png", startx, starty)

class Box(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, startx, starty):
        super().__init__("woodenboxbutsmaller.png", startx, starty)

def game_loop():
    pygame.init()
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    player = Player(200,400)
    
    boxes = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for bx in range(0,800,1400):
        boxes.add(Box(bx,600))

    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        player.update()

        #draw loop
        gameDisplay.fill(background)
        player.draw(gameDisplay)
        boxes.draw(gameDisplay)
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60) # 60fps frame rate

game_intro()
```

I'm not very adept at programming and I just need this to work for a school project

Comment: typo: `self.image = pygame.image.load(image)` instead of `self.image = pygame.image.load('stickman.png')` (in class `Sprite`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your application. It has to be `self.image = pygame.image.load(image)` instead of `self.image = pygame.image.load('stickman.png')` (in class `Sprite`).